# Lazy loading - fontawesome

Tags: web, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have a site that is using fontawesome. I am lazy loading many of the CSS files to increase first page load time, etc.

However, I need the fa-phone-alt to working on first load because it appears at the top of the page.

Can anyone provide guidance as to how I an add inline style just for the fa-phone-alt so that it works without having to load the entire style sheet?

Hope I am explaining this well enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to solve exactly what you're asking, but a workaround could be that you download an SVG of a phone and place it so it loads instantly.